# Passing parameters to constructors with no parameters

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I am trying to understand the what the program I am using is doing. Below, I included the relevant pieces of the code.

An pointer of class `StAnaPars` is created:

`StAnaPars* anapars12 = new StAnaPars;`

The program accesses several members of `anapars12` to set different analysis parameters.

Then, another pointer of class `StAnaPars` is created as follows:

`StAnaPars *anapars12_toward = new StAnaPars(*anapars12);`

The definition of the constructor for the class `StAnaPars` is:

```
   23 class StAnaPars : public TObject {
   24 public:
   25   StAnaPars()
   26     : mCorrectTowerEnergyForTracks(new StjTowerEnergyCorrectionForTracksNull)
   27     , useTpc(false)
   28     , useBemc(false)
   29     , useEemc(false)
   30     , useFms(false)
   31     , useMonteCarlo(false)
   32     , randomSelectorProb(1.0)
   33     , randomSelectorAt(false)
   34     , randomSelectorSeed(0)
   35     , changeTracks(0)
   36     , changeTowers(0)
   37   {
   38   }
```

My question is, when the second `StAnaPars` pointer is created, `anapars12_toward`, we set it equal to `new StAnaPars(*anapars12)`, but the constructor of `StAnaPars` doesn't accept any parameter. So, is what this is doing basically making a copy of `anapars12` and now `anapars12_toward = anapars12`? So, both pointers have the same information? But how can we do this when the `StAnaPars` constructor doesn't accept any parameters?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: copy constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is using the copy constructor.

A copy constructor is a constructor declared as `T(const T& other)`. It can be user defined or, when no user defined copy constructor exists, it is *implicitly* defined and does a member-wise copy.

If you want to explicitly disallow copying, you can declare the copy constructor as:

`T(const T&) = delete;`

The same is true for copy assignment - `T& operator=(const T& other)` (it is also implicitly defined).

There are actually some non-trivial rules about when exactly an implicit copy constructor is actually *defined*, though. Sometimes, it is implicitly *declared* as deleted. (for example, if the type has members with no copy constructor). A summary of the rules can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor